# Deploy automated builds to TestFlight from an Xcode 7 Bot

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7, testflight

Want to deploy build automatically to TestFlight with Xcode 7,many scripts are available,but all are before the Apple owned the TestFlight.Stuck for many hours,any help would be appreciated...:)